# Wildcards as shell parameters

Tags: linux, shell, ls

I know how regex and wildcards work in general, but I don't really understand why you can use them as parameters.

```
ls /[!\(][!\(][!\(]/
```

command results in the following output

```
...
com.apple.launchd.AIPZ6SAfpO
com.apple.launchd.HarlOx3LWS
com.apple.launchd.VmTi5KDz1h
powerlog

/usr/:
X11     include     libexec     sbin        standalone
bin     lib     local       share

/var/:
agentx      empty       log     netboot     rwho
at      folders     ma      networkd    spool
audit       install     mail        root        tmp
backups     jabberd     msgs        rpc     vm
db      lib     mysql       run     yp
```

from my understanding this should match every three character folder name not containing slash `/[!\(][!\(][!\(]/`

But why can I use it as parameter?

Comment: What's your question again? Why can or _can't_ you use?

Comment: The shell applies the glob pattern to the contents of the file system, using the current directory, unless your pattern starts with `/`.  The result is then passed to the command.  You can see what matches if you replace the command with `echo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use regular expressions as parameters (or rather, the shell will not treat a string as a regular expression when placed in a parameter). The [unquoted](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) [**glob**](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) `/[!\(][!\(][!\(]/` matches, in order:

1. A slash.
2. Three characters which are not starting brackets.
3. A slash.

In other words, **three-letter root directories not containing `(` anywhere.**

---

The shell *expands* globs to zero (in case of Bash's nullglob, for example) or more arguments which may be passed to `execve`, as in this command:

```
$ strace -fe execve echo *
execve("/usr/bin/echo", ["echo", "directory1", "directory2"], 0x7ffcff705ce8 /* 44 vars */) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Not, you don't know.... shell patterns are described in `glob(3)` while regular expressions (a more elaborate concept) are described in `regex(3)`  Two different libraries used for similar purposes.  `sh(1)` doesn't use regular expressions when substituting parameters at all.  It only uses the `glob(3)` library.

Answer (score -1):

Because that's how the shell works. Any arguments containing (unquoted) glob characters/expressions, are expanded to filenames. That's what happens in, say `rm *.txt` (since `*` is a glob character), and that's what happens in `ls /[!\(][!\(][!\(]/` (since `[abc]` is a glob expression).

They're not regular expressions, though. See e.g. https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob for the syntax.

Comment: Yes, globs are a reduced set of regular expressions.  They don't have all the power of complete regular expressions, but they are quite powerful anyway.